# DateTime.Now ignoring windows 10 settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, .net-4.5, windows-10

Code:

```
Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
```

Output:23/09/2015

Instead of: 09/23/15

[image]

Comment: asp.net mvc application?

Comment: old school web forms asp.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check web.config for autodetection culture:

```
<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" enableClientBasedCulture="true"/>
```

in `<system.web>`

Or set it manually:

```
<globalization culture="en-us" uiCulture="en-us" />
```

Comment: I see this there now     <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>

Comment: @CodeMilian it's just encoding, try to add `culture` and `uiculture` attributes

Comment: @CodeMilian glad to know, can you accept the answer?

Comment: I will but it says I need to wait 6 more minutes.